# Array filling mistake

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't understand what's wrong is in my program. I have such input data:

```
01000
11110
01000
```

I want to save it into: `vector< vector<int> > matrix;`

```
vector< vector<int> > fillMatrix(vector< vector<int> > matrix, int height, int width, ifstream &read)
{
    // Make 2d-array [matrix]
    matrix.resize(width);
    for (int i=0; i < width; ++i)
        matrix[i].resize(height);

    // Fill it up with data
    for (int i=0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        std::string tempLine;
        std::getline(read, tempLine);
        for (int j=0; j < tempLine.length(); ++j)
        {
            // This shows right information
            //std::cout << tempLine[j] << "  -  " << (int)(tempLine[j] - '0') << "\n";
            matrix[i][j] = (int)(tempLine[j] - '0');
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

matrix = fillMatrix(matrix, 3, 5, ifstreamHandle);
```

And now, function which shows the matrix:

```
void showMatrix(vector< vector<int> > matrix, int width, int height)
{
    // Show the matrix
    for (int i=0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

showMatrix(matrix, 5, 3);
```

And the result of `showMatrix` is:

```
01000
11100
01000
```

There are missed '1' in second row. What's wrong?

Comment: You should really be passing the matrix by reference.  When you pass by value it copies the entire matrix unnecessarily.

Comment: As a random aside, is there any reason for taking the parameters in as (height, width) the first time and (width, height) the second time?  I almost thought that was the bug until I noticed the ordering was different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialise the vector, you have width and height the wrong way around. When you later read from the last two columns, the results will be undefined.

```
matrix.resize(width);
for (int i=0; i < width; ++i)
    matrix[i].resize(height);
```

should be

```
matrix.resize(height);
for (int i=0; i < height; ++i)
    matrix[i].resize(width);
```

Your `fillMatrix` function has `width` and `height` in a different order to that in which you call it later in `showMatrix`. I would advise swapping the order in `fillMatrix` to keep it the same as in `showMatrix`.

Be careful filling each row up to `tempLine.length`, which may be greater than `width` which will cause an exception. You could also just get the width and height from the vector within `showMatrix` instead of having these as arguments. And as @Charles says, you should really pass the vector by reference to avoid a copy being made. The vector argument in `fillMatrix` is currently pretty useless given that you have to return it, unless you turn it into a reference and make the function `void`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are not consistent in your code

```
for (int i=0; i < width; ++i)
...
for (int i=0; i < height; ++i)
```

so you are creating matrix like `matrix[i].resize(3)` for `i = 0..4`, but write into it using `matrix[i][j]` where `i = 0..2` and `j=0..4`